# How to make redirect_to work in remote form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form and my goal is

- if the form submission is successful...redirect to home page
- if the form submission is unsuccessful....show error message in bootstrap modal

if I used normal form (not remote)

```
    <%= form_with model: @car, id: "car-form", local: true do |f| %>
```

then redirect_to is working but the code for bootstrap modal that i wrote in action.js.erb not executing

if I used remote form

```
    <%= form_with model: @car, id: "car-form", remote: true do |f| %>
```

then redirect_to stops working but the code for bootstrap modal that i wrote in action.js.erb is executing

I need both...Is there any way for it?

Comment: Add an [ajax handler](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers) and check if the response is a 201 Created status code (you have to actually set the correct status codes from the controller). If so redirect to the location in the location header with `window.location` or `Turbolinks.visit`.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note:

1) `form_with` is a `remote: true` by default. When you pass `local` then it's a non ajax form. Look at this [form_with reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with)

2) If you want to hit your `action.js.erb` then in your controller, you call the `format.js`

One way:

```
def action_name
  @foo = Foo.bar

  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.errors.any?
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :index }
    end
  end
end
```

Another way:

```
Your controller action
----------------------
def action_name
  @foo = Foo.bar

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end


action.js.erb
----------------

<% if @foo.errors.count > 0 %>
  your modal with errors in it
<% else %>
  window.location.href='<%= url_for(:action => :index) %>'
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sri wrote above you might differ thet by `format` or in simplest way use `flash` Rails provides method to display `flash` mathod in the same request by `flash.now`

so making a form `local: true` and in controller:

```
if @foo.save
  render 'something_new'
else
  flash.now[:error] @foo.errors.map(&:message).join(', ')
  render 'edit' // render the same view with form
end
```

(or do similar to get proper error massages or your own message)

next you can display it over form as a modal:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <div class='modal'>
  ...
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

also making modal visible on start

```
$(".modal").modal('show')
```